# I thought I was buying EOS

Tags: ether, tokens, addresses

I attempted to purchase what I thought was EOS tokens 2 days ago. Now I'had a look and found two transactions for 0.2 and 1 ether but don't know what address it is for.

TxHash: `0x81ae7065961eaabfd098bc792fa5d2e4ce33d0bdb66276b910d5f8c111971847`

Block: `4674826`

Address from: `0xf809849f38ec935ea211a7aeb9e86da56568a662`

Address to: `0x9ba5ae67fd01a2d21cb662961f70cd29dbbcc886`

For the second transaction (1 ether):

TxHash: `0xd96bb9bcf56417f1cba401cd1134c25f4ac4d499483bc8edc29ee0d088651db1`

Block: `4674874`

Addresses are the same.

I would be grateful for any advice on how I can confirm if this is indeed an EOS address.

Thanks

Comment: Which service did you sue to buy the EOS tokens? The official website?

Comment: Yes I did and went straight from myetherwallet. There was a whole lot of trouble with the network and I received a lot of cancelled transactions (not enough gas). I also tried buying another token (BitDegree) but nothing was going through. Hence, I'm a little lost. My apologies for the amateurish questions.

Comment: What is strange is that that 1 ether went from the address above to this address:  0xE2ac3F00401c8Ee3f72f30F54B92fd38cD3368CE   which seems to be an ICO address. Is there any way of confirming what an address might be? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot. I think I just worked it out. That 0.2 ETH you highlighted is for EOS but the two transactions below it were the ones I was wondering about. I just confirmed that they were for the INS token. My sincere apologies and thank you for your prompt help.

Answer (score 1):

From your etherscan profile, it looks like you sent 0.2 ETH to buy EOS. Check [here](https://etherscan.io/address/0xf809849f38ec935ea211a7aeb9e86da56568a662).